# How to point CNAME to specific webpage/URL?

Tags: php, cname

I'm not even sure if this is possible or if I'm explaining it right but I'll give it a shot.

So basically I'm creating a web application using Javascript, HTML, CSS, SQL and PHP. I'm pretty new to backend web development, though everything is going great so far. Things are working exactly how I planned and I'm pretty proud of myself.

I have multiple users and when you go to their profile (domain.com/user/1) it displays all their info. This works the same for domain.com/user/2, domain.com/user/3 and so on.

What I'm trying to do is allow users to point their domain/subdomain to a CNAME (such as verify.mydomain.com) which allows them to connect their subdomain/domain to the web application so that it displays the same as what domain.com/user/1 does.

For example, user1 can use their domain profile.mydomain.com and it displays what domain.com/user/1 does but keeping the subdomain rather than a redirect.

If anyone has any suggestions at all on how I can do this please let me know!

Comment: If you are on Apache I would recommend using a `mod_rewrite` `.htaccess` routine to do exactly this, that silently on the server `user2.domain.com/` is shown but loads `domain.com/user/2`

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry about my English!*

I'm not sure if you are using a self-host or a shared-host, but to solve it, you need to make some configurations(no worry, they are easy):

**#1. DNS**

By default your DNS server has some record like:

```
100.100.100.100 www.mywebsite.com
```

so, you need to change it to somethink like:

```
* .mywebsite.com
```

Please check if this configuration can cause some problem (I don't know if you have another application is this domain)

**#2. WebServer**

If you are using Apache as webserver  you only need to add/change "ServerAlias" directive and the VirtualHost name (if necessary) to somethink like:

```
<VirtualHost test.local:80>
    DocumentRoot "YOUR_APP_PATH"
    ServerName test.local
    ServerAlias *.test.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Now all subdomains(test.com, [www.test.com](http://www.test.com) and user1.test.com) will be redirect to some app directory.

**3#. Your APP**

Now you need to adjust your application logic to understand the URL and make the necessary requests.